# Better player Rotation feature conflicts between rotation button click v/s device orientation change

Tags: flutter, rotation, orientation, fullscreen

I am using the better player in one of our latest application and there I am working on Rotation feature of video when click on button or when the device orientation changed.

So here, the rotation feature is working fine in iOS version 15 and less. But for the iOS version 16.0 or more, it's conflicting.

Can anyone help me here please?

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Try to rotate the device to toggle the full screen mode.
It keeps getting conflict when user try to toggle full screen mode with device rotation and full screen button click.
Also, Here consider YouTube application as reference for toggle full screen from various places (device orientation, full screen button click and Swipe up to open full screen and swipe down to close full screen.

Better Player version
Version: latest

Smartphone:
OS: iOS 16.0 +

I have tried to make the rotation working by the events of the app lifecycle to detect the orientation of the device and based on that orientation and current full screen flag, it will toggle the full screen.

But it result into conflict between the full screen toggle from device rotation and full screen button click.

Case: When video in full screen, and user click on the exit full screen button, Then video will back to normal screen and again go to the full screen automatically.